# Webflux streaming Nginx exception

Tags: spring, nginx, spring-webflux, spring-cloud-stream

I have Spring Cloud SSE #webflux streaming service, and my front connect with it via Nginx. Some times I have this:

```
Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONTENT_LENGTH_MISMATCH
 the server responded with a status of 504 (Gateway Timeout)
```

Event source with retry again reconnect and it works.

Front code looks like this

```
this.source = new EventSource("/comment/stream", { });

this.source.addEventListener("message", function (event)
```

backend side

```
 @GetMapping(path = "/comment/stream", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
    public Flux<Comment> feed() {

        return this.commentRepository.findAll();
    }
```

Configuring netty with timeout does not help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was from real timout 60s from spring cloud gateway in front of this streaming service.